# Is the Potential Duplicate Standard Component also for Custom Objects on the roadmap?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, duplicate-management

I found that there is an Potential Duplicate Lightning Component (Standard) available for Lead, Accounts and Contacts. The components has also a merge process build in. This is very nice and important for Data Quality. However this component is not available for any Custom Objects or other standard objects. The process and the logic behind this should be very similar for any objects.

The components is the second in the right panel - the one with the yellow icon and the bold text.

[image]

Here is the documentation on that feature: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicates_existing_setup.htm&type=5

We have already created a custom lightning component for any objects (pink icon with the bell), but it is still buggy and the merge process is incomplete. Especially the merge is a lot of work and I found a strange behavior on DuplicateRecordItem (this is elaborated in [this question here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/196169))

I want to plan ahead and avoid wasting time to create things which will eventually become available as standard.

So I would like to know if there is an update for this components on the roadmap which will be usable in the same manner, but for all objects - standard as well as custom? Any hint under Safeharbor is highly appreciated.

Comment: FYI this [Lightning Components Roadmap](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_components_roadmap.htm&type=0) page, though that is more about UI widgets than substantial functionality components; no mention there of custom record duplicate detection.

Comment: @KeithC yes, I know that. It covers only the lightning namespace, but not those standard components which implements flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes - exactly this roadmap would be, what I'm looking for. Possibly this is top-secret, which would be very bad for all of us, but even that I would accept as an answer. But right now, I have absolutely no information, hence any kind of planning is impossible...

Comment: Even if you get that sort of information it would be Safe Harbor and explicitly not given for the purpose of making plans around.

Comment: @AdrianLarson would be way better than nothing. I can live with Safe Harbor.

Comment: in the meantime we have implemented such a component on our own. it is working ok - but not 100%. It is a HUGE thing, especially if it comes to merging related records, dealing with mandatory fields and custom validations...

Answer (score 1):

This idea asks for the same:

> ## [Idea to expand Potential Duplicates component to work with custom objects](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CSx5QAG)
>
> Currently missing the ability to show potential duplicates in Lightning for custom objects. This would be a very powerful feature.

Given that it is not yet delivered, it seems what you want is not available.

Comment: in the meantime we have implemented such a component on our own. it is working ok - but not 100%. It is a HUGE thing, especially if it comes to merging related records, dealing with mandatory fields and custom validations...