# New duplicate rule not firing for existing records

Tags: administration, duplicate-management

I have created a new duplicate rule on account which does a fuzzy company name match and reports duplicates for inserts. I have the duplicate rule set to fire for edits as well and I created a dummy field on account hoping that update to that field would fire the duplicate rule and create a duplicate set with all matches in the account object. I tried to update that field for all accounts via data loader with batch size 1. I don't see the duplicate rule firing or logging the duplicate records in the objects DuplicateRecordSet or DuplicateRecordItem. Can anyone please let me know what I am missing here or if there is a different approach to get the duplicates logged into duplicateRecordItems for reporting.

[image: Duplicate Rule]

Comment: did you try running a [Duplicate Job](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_jobs_run_and_manage.htm&type=5)?

Comment: what do you mean by duplicate job? I ran the data loader update.

Comment: i'm suggesting in lieu of Data Loader to use the Duplicate Jobs feature to create the duplicate set - see link above

Comment: we are on enterprise edition and looks like the duplicate jobs are not available in enterprise edition

Comment: investigate whether duplicate rules fire ONLY when one of the fields in the matching rule changes (as opposed to updating the dummy field in Data Loader)

Comment: Even if you run the duplicate job and it finds the duplicate (Creates a DRS Record); this is not a guarantee that the rule is firing on the contact. See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/196171/why-duplicaterecorditem-is-working-only-after-insert-and-not-after-update-of-the